# Git command output shows special characters

Tags: git, special-characters, vi

For the past few days, we are seeing a strange behavior on executing Git commands.

**Command executed:** git show 08fcf54adc7bbb75a54b14625fdeea7608d44a23 > sample.patch

On opening the file sample.patch through **vi editor**, we are seeing a lot of special characters; a sample output file looks like:

```
^[[33mcommit 08fcf54adc7bbb75a54b14625fdeea7608d44a23^[[m

 Author: Anshul Gupta <anshul.gupta@lnttechservices.com>

 Date:   Wed Nov 26 23:27:20 2014 +0400

     Remove redundant logs from EPD driver

     Change-Id: I078584ddd7a58da1052a8d46fd59af722e11136b

 ^[[1mdiff --git a/drivers/video/s1d13522/s1d13522fb.c b/drivers/video/s1d13522/s1d13522fb.c^[[m

 ^[[1mindex ca568ad..5e67de6 100644^[[m

 ^[[1m--- a/drivers/video/s1d13522/s1d13522fb.c^[[m

 ^[[1m+++ b/drivers/video/s1d13522/s1d13522fb.c^[[m

 ^[[36m@@ -1099,7 +1099,7 @@^[[m ^[[mstatic void s1d13522fb_display_init_wq(struct work_struct *work)^[[m
```

**Note1:** The issue is seen only for one particular user(on Ubuntu server). So possibly it looks like the configuration issue with Git or maybe vi editor.

**Note2:** The normal file redirection seems to be working fine. Example cat abc > xyz, the contents are copied properly with no special characters

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Those are color sequences, so it means the user has requested that git *always* produce color sequences, even if the output is not going to a color terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Git color settings. It looks like they're set to *true* for this particular user, but you want to use *auto* instead.

The characters you're seeing are color codes for the terminal. With a color setting of *auto*, they shouldn't be visible when piping to vi.

Check out a more detailed question/answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44266/how-to-colorize-output-of-git

Git Documentation: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Colors-in-Git

The default value is *auto*, so it looks like the user in question has a local configuration overriding the default values.